# I have difficulties using the Live server extension in vscode in my windows PC

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I am a newbie in JavaScript. I just downloaded the Live server extension in VScode. When i go live by clicking on the 'GO LIVE' in the VScode status bar, my server is started at a particular port but it doesn't open up my default browser which is chrome so that i can see the outcome of my code.
I am really stuck and i need help. Thanks in anticipation for taking your time to help me fix this.

Comment: Are you sure that you set Chrome to be your default browser?

Comment: Yes i set my default browser as chrome in my google chrome settings. Is there a place to set it to chrome in VScode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your `settings.json`:

```
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"
```

(On Windows `%AppData%\Code\User\settings.json`, on Linux  `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`, and on macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`)

Note: Make sure to add a Comma to the end of the previous line inside of the json. Example:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0, //note the comma at the end here
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"
}
```

Comment: This really helped. I set "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"